# Unable to change the values of the mapping data in text field

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have my data in array format inside the object.

Here is the JSON data:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "details": [
      { "id": "12wer1", "name": "ABC", "age": 15 },
      { "id": "78hbg5", "name": "FRE", "age": 21 }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "details": [
      { "id": "po78u9", "name": "TER", "age": 18 },
      { "id": "dre87u", "name": "YUN", "age": 30 }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to change the name and age with respective of the "id". It should not get change for another "id". For Example: if i want to change name = "ABC" then it should not change for the Name="FRE". But couldn't able to do that.

Can anyone help me in writing proper onChange funtion for this and validation for text field?

Here is the sample code:

```
{this.state.Data.map((i) => (
          <>
            {i.details.map((y) => (
              <Grid container justify="center" spacing={2}>
                <Grid item xs={3}>
                  <TextField label="Name" variant="outlined" value={y.name} />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={3}>
                  <TextField label="Age" variant="outlined" value={y.age} />
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            ))}{" "}
          </>
        ))}
      </>
```

[Here is the working code](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-sky-vxql4)

Comment: I've answered below with a way fairly standard way to update nested state. What sort of validation are you referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an onChange handler that consumes the outer and inner array indices, and `onChange` event and map the old state to the new state using the map index to match the object you want to update.

```
handleChange = (dataIndex, detailIndex) => (e) => {
  const { id, value } = e.target;
  this.setState(({ Data }) => ({
    Data: Data.map((dataItem, data_index) =>
      data_index === dataIndex
        ? {
            ...dataItem,
            details: dataItem.details.map((item, index) =>
              index === detailIndex
                ? {
                    ...item,
                    [id]: value
                  }
                : item
            )
          }
        : dataItem
    )
  }));
};
```

Provide the `id` attributes for the inputs to pass in the event object.

```
{this.state.Data.map((i, dataIndex) => ( // <-- data index
  <>
    {i.details.map((y, detailIndex) => ( // <-- detail index
      <Grid container justify="center" spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={3}>
          <TextField
            label="Name"
            id="name" // <-- id name attribute
            variant="outlined"
            value={y.name}
            onChange={this.handleChange(dataIndex, detailIndex)} // <-- onChange callback
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={3}>
          <TextField
            label="Age"
            id="age" // <-- id age attribute
            variant="outlined"
            value={y.age}
            onChange={this.handleChange(dataIndex, detailIndex)} // <-- onChange callback
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    ))}{" "}
  </>
))}
```

[image: Edit unable-to-change-the-values-of-the-mapping-data-in-text-field]

Answer (score 1):

you need to create an `onChange` handler and pass to `TextField` to proper see your value being updated, otherwise it will remain static. Given each object in array has an `id` you can use it to filter the target object. Make sure to create copies to avoid mutate state directly:

```
  onChange = (e, itemId, detailId) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const Data = [...this.state.Data]; // copy Data into new array
    const itemIndex = Data.findIndex((item) => item.id === itemId);

    if (itemIndex === -1) return; // return if item not found
    const item = { ...Data[itemIndex] }; // copy item object
    const detailsIndex = item.details.findIndex(
      (detail) => detail.id === detailId
    );

    if (detailsIndex === -1) return; // return if detail not found
    item.details[detailsIndex] = {
      ...item.details[detailsIndex],
      [name]: value
    };
    Data[itemIndex] = item; // pass new item
    this.setState({ Data });
  };
```

At `TextField` pass `name` attribute, so you can extract `e.target.name` above. your `TextField` becomes:

```
<Grid item xs={3}>
  <TextField
    label="Name"
    name="name"
    variant="outlined"
    value={y.name}
    onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e, i.id, y.id)}
  />
</Grid>
<Grid item xs={3}>
  <TextField
    label="Age"
    name="age"
    variant="outlined"
    value={y.age}
    onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e, i.id, y.id)}
  />
</Grid>
```

[image: deep-nested-state-handler]